# Group and sum fields in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, sum, grouping

I have a json like this and I want to calculate the sum of the fields, group by its Flag value

```
$scope.staffs =  [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Management",
            "Flag": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Revenue Collection/Ledger",
            "Flag": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Office Assistance",
            "Flag": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Operators (Source)",
            "Flag": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Operators (WTP)",
            "Flag": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Operators at Networks",
            "Flag": 2
        }
    ]
```

and my html is like this here what I want is when user put value to Permanent field it should find it Flag value and calculate sum of the Permanent fields with that Flag value and if Flag value is 1 put sum in **wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total** and if Flag value is 2 put sum  to **wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total**

```
<div ng-repeat="wspStaffTbl in staffs">
{{ wspStaffTbl.name }}
<input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Permanent" ng-change="updatePermanentTotal()">
</div>

<input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total">
<input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total">
```

what I tried is

```
$scope.updatePermanentTotal = function(){
  $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total = 0;
  $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total = 0;

  angular.forEach($scope.staffs, function(value, key){

    if(!isNaN(parseInt(value.Permanent))){
       if(value.Flag==1){
            $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total = $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total + parseInt(value.Permanent);
          }
    if(value.Flag==2){
            $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total = $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total + parseInt(value.Permanent);  
          }
    }
 })
}
```

but it is not working as expected.

Comment: running this function on every change will cost you a lot of performance...

Comment: yeah i know is there any other way?

Comment: debouncing will resolve your performance problem... https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#debounce

Comment: I will check this later for now I just have to solve my above problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I hope that's what you wish for...**

***app.js***

```
var myApp = angular.module('test' , []);
myApp.controller('test_ctrl' , function($scope){
    $scope.staffs =  [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Management",
            "Flag": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Revenue Collection/Ledger",
            "Flag": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Office Assistance",
            "Flag": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Operators (Source)",
            "Flag": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Operators (WTP)",
            "Flag": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Operators at Networks",
            "Flag": 2
        }
    ];

    $scope.updatePermanentTotal = function(){
        $scope.wspStaffTotal = {
            Admin_Perm_Total: 0,
            Technical_Perm_Total :0
        }

        angular.forEach($scope.staffs, function(value, index){

            if(!isNaN(parseInt(value.Permanent))){
                if(value.Flag==1){
                    $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total = $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total + parseInt(value.Permanent);

                }
                if(value.Flag==2){
                    $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total = $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total + parseInt(value.Permanent);
                }
            }else{
                console.log("value is NAN");
            }

        });
        alert("result flag1:{" +$scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total+"} flag2: {" +$scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total +"}" );
    }
});
```

***HTML***

```
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="test_ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="wspStaffTbl in staffs">
    {{ wspStaffTbl.name }}
    <input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Permanent" ng-change="updatePermanentTotal()">
</div>

<input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total">
<input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $scope.wspStaffTotal = {
            Admin_Perm_Total: 0,
            Technical_Perm_Total :0
        }

make it work

You try mine?

Comment: When you make the code like yours:
$scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total = 0;
  $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total = 0;
 if you look in the console its said that  "cannot find Admin_Perm_Total  of undefined" because you don't initialize the variable    $scope.wspStaffTotal , so... what i do is just initialize it :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

first of all make the permanent value an array in the controller

```
$scope.webStaffTbl.Permanent = [];
```

then pass these to values to the function:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Permanent[$index]" ng-change="updatePermanentTotal(wspStaffTbl.Permanent[$index],wspStaffTbl.flag)">
```

and pass the permanent value with its flag to the function

and then in the $scope function do this :

```
$scope.updatePermanentTotal = function(permanentValue,flag){


$scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total = 0;
  $scope.wspStaffTotal.Technical_Perm_Total = 0;

  angular.forEach($scope.staffs, function(value, key){

    if(!isNaN(parseInt(permanentValue))){
       if(flag==1){

            $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total = $scope.wspStaffTotal.Admin_Perm_Total + parseInt(permanentValue);
          }
    if(flag==2){

          }
    }
 })
}
```